# Fatal singnal11 and webview doesnt load properly

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I'm trying to load a webpage in a webview but the screen is stuck on loading on the page. It opens the website but after the loading it should display the content - but instead of that I'm experiencing continuous loading. Also sometimes istead of the app to start it crashes with this from logCat:

```
02-18 21:25:12.780: D/dalvikvm(9079): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 81% free 488K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms
02-18 21:25:12.790: D/jdwp(9079): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-18 21:25:12.790: D/dalvikvm(9079): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-18 21:25:13.040: D/dalvikvm(9103): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-18 21:25:13.040: I/ActivityManager(310): Start proc com.example.testbrowser for activity com.example.testbrowser/.MainActivity: pid=9103 uid=10079 gids={3003}
02-18 21:25:13.270: D/TextLayoutCache(9103): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
02-18 21:25:13.310: D/SurfaceFlinger(138): Release buffer at 0xb9888
02-18 21:25:13.320: D/libEGL(9103): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-18 21:25:13.340: D/libEGL(9103): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-18 21:25:13.380: D/libEGL(9103): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-18 21:25:13.380: D/libEGL(9103): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-18 21:25:13.990: I/ActivityManager(310): No longer want ch.bitspin.timely (pid 8858): hidden #16
02-18 21:25:14.000: D/OpenGLRenderer(9103): Enabling debug mode 0
02-18 21:25:14.300: I/ActivityManager(310): Displayed com.example.testbrowser/.MainActivity: +1s494ms
02-18 21:25:14.320: A/libc(9103): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
02-18 21:25:14.510: D/SurfaceFlinger(138): Release buffer at 0xbd670
02-18 21:25:14.730: I/DEBUG(136): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-18 21:25:14.730: I/DEBUG(136): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/LT18i_1254-2219/LT18i:4.0.4/4.1.B.0.587/tL1_3w:user/release-keys'
02-18 21:25:14.730: I/DEBUG(136): pid: 9103, tid: 9124  >>> com.example.testbrowser <<<
02-18 21:25:14.730: I/DEBUG(136): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
02-18 21:25:14.730: I/DEBUG(136):  r0 00000000  r1 00000001  r2 00348c78  r3 00000000
```

I've added internet permission to the manifest and this is my class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://b2b.snowinstructors.eu/app/snowbook-app/";
        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not call `loadUrl` inside your implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. This creates a loop.